# sqlite3 combining multiple databases into 1

Tags: database, bash, shell, sqlite

I have created 1000 `.db` files that have the same tables but different records. I am trying to take all the records in them and insert them into a single database:

```
for i in {0..1099}; do
sqlite3 .dump $i.db | sqlite3 results.db
done;
```

However, the following error is produced:

```
 Error: unrecognized token: "0.db"
 Error: unrecognized token: "1.db"
 etc.
```

Comment: `sqlite3 --help 2>&1 | grep Usage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems

1. the command should be the 2nd argument, after the db
2. it will fail for the 2nd file as the table is created by the 1st

then, you can do this

```
for d in {0..1000}.db
do
    sqlite3 "$d" .dump
done | sed 's@\(CREATE TABLE\)\(.*\);@\1 IF NOT EXISTS \2;@' | sqlite3 results.db
```

which creates the table if it doesn't exist.